# How to send C-style array to objective-c method

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, methods

I am trying to send c-style array of integers to objective-c method, but in method I recieve only first element of array.
This is an example:

```
int a[3];
a[0] = 111;   a[1] = 222;   a[2] = 333;
[self getMatrix:a];
```

then

```
-(void)getMatrix:(int[3])matrix
{
    return;      -- breakpoint here
}
```

So, when debugging stops at breakpoint, i have matrix:

```
matrix  int *   0xbfffddd4
*matrix int 111
```

Where are other elements?
So, 2d-arrays become to 1d array, 3d-array become 2d-array etc.
What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

P.S. NSArray is working fine ofc, but I can't imagine how to work with multidimensional (3d, 4d) NSArrays w/o writing tonns of code.

Comment: You can put `NSArrays` as elements of `NSArray`s. And for solving your problem you should have a look into call by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)getMatrix:(int[3])matrix
{
    int a = matrix[0];
    int b = matrix[1];
    int c = matrix[2];
}
```

You will see that the values are correct. There is nothing wrong. The debugger is only showing  `*matrix` which is the first element. Here `matrix` itself is a pointer to integer or `int *`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send pointer to first item and size of array through.

See how

`- (void)setLineDash:(const CGFloat *)pattern count:(NSInteger)count phase:(CGFloat)phase`

in NSBezierPath does this.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html